# How to receive numbers pressed on a keypad of calling party while ringing in Android?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am working on an android app and i wanted to know if it is possible to receive the numbers or DTMF tone or any such related data at the called party's phone, that the calling party is typing on his/her phone while the phone of the called party is ringing.

Just to make the question more clearer, consider this scenario with two people A and B :

1. Caller **A** is calling **B**.
2. **B**'s phone is **ringing**.
3. **A** types a sequence or a single digit on his phone while it is **still ringing**.
4. Those digits are received at **B**'s phone.
5. Based on what digit / what sequence it is, an action will be triggered at **B**'s phone (Through my app).

I just wanted to know if the above scenario or anything equivalent or remotely like the same is possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. First, we have no access to the in-call audio stream, except perhaps if the phone is in speakerphone mode. Second, I am not aware of any Android device that plays the audio of the incoming call over top of the ringing where the user has not picked up the phone.

Comment: I completely understood the first part, but i did not understand what you meant by this - "I am not aware of any Android device that plays the audio of the incoming call over top of the ringing where the user has not picked up the phone." 

In any which case, is there no way we can send ANY kind of information except "disconnecting signal" from the calling party to the called party while ringing ?

Comment: @Sushruth: "i did not understand what you meant by this" -- your requirement is to be able to receive DTMF tones *before the call is acccepted*. This implies that Android would be playing those DTMF tones *while the phone is ringing*, and I am not aware that any device does that. "is there no way we can send ANY kind of information except "disconnecting signal" from the calling party to the called party while ringing ?" -- you can't even send "disconnecting signal", whatever that is.

Comment: By "disconnecting signal", i meant the one used to 'dropping the call before the called party picks up the call' but now i realized that it is sent to the service provider and not the called party directly!. Thanks for your patience! now i understand.